# How to test login via google by cypress?

Tags: testing, https, automated-tests, cypress, registration

After clicking on buttons, that redirects to google i have such error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjuNZ.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please expand your question by showing the expected result as well as the result you are not satisfied with.  Possibly show any log file passages where the error message is contained.  Last but not least, show us your efforts that were unsuccessful.

Comment: What I can say checking the image with the results is that you need to log into a Web page using auth0. You should probably use cy.request(). The Cypress documentation has a nice article about that: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/testing-strategies/auth0-authentication#Auth0-Application-Setup